# How to get IFTTT Maker Applet API Key for AWS IoT Button

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, ifttt

I'm trying to connect my AWS IoT Button to do an IFTTT Maker Trigger, and it's asking for the API Key. I've looked in the settings of the IFTTT Maker Applet I created, and I don't see anything about an API Key. Any ideas of where else to look inside of IFTTT? They don't have a way to contact IFTTT Tech Support that I could find. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *IFTTT* app or through their website whilst logged in, go to *My Applets > Services > Webhooks > Settings*.  The settings page will list your *Maker* URL, and the key is the alphanumeric string at the end.  If you click on the URL, it will take you to your *Maker* webpage that specifically tells you what your key is, and provides instructions on how to use the webhook.

Comment: This no longer appears to function.

Comment: @ChrisK How so?

Comment: I cannot find *Services* under *Applets*

Answer (score 4):

At the time of this writing, this appears to be the correct place to find the API key:

https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010230347-Webhooks-service-FAQ

Under the Documentation Link of the Webhooks service page.

Comment: To find it from your home screen, click on your account avatar in the upper right corner of the home screen and select `My Services`, and then click `Webhooks`.  The Documentation button is upper right in the page.  As of 2/2021, anyway.

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2022